# POSTmethod and PHP- login verification

Tags: php

I wrote a code for login verification..I got output with GET. But i need output with POST since it is more secure.pls let me know if there is any error in my code.

javascript code:

```
var xml;
function verifyusernamepasswd(pass)
{
//pass is password that will be passed as parameter
xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="http://localhost/loginvalidate.php";
var para="q="+username+"&p="+pass;//username is global
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-length", para.length);
xml.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xml.open("POST",url,true);
xml.onreadystatechange=statechanged1;
xml.send(para);

}

function statechanged1()
{
if(xml.readyState==4)
alert(xml.responseText);

}


php code:

<?php
$username=$_POST["q"];
$password=$_POST["p"];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","blaze");
if(!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: '.mysql.error());
}
mysql_select_db("BLAZE",$con) or die("No such Db");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Passwword FROM USERTABLE WHERE Userhandle='$username'");
if($result==null)
echo "false";

else if($result!=null)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if((strcmp($row['Passwword'],$password)==0))
echo "true";
else
echo "false";
}

?>
```

the verification does not return anything, cos my alert is not displayed at all...pls tell me whats wrong....

Comment: Please start doing some debugging by reacting to other `readyState`s than 4 - you may get back an error message that explains what's wrong. That's the usual way of going about stuff like this, step for step debugging. Then, it might be worth looking into a JS Framework like JQuery, it makes AJAX calls *much* easier: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/. Then, you have a big fat SQL injection but I made you aware of that already in the last question so I'm not re-posting the links here :)

Comment: but do you think the formats are all correct? like do i have to add anything extra for getting POST to work?yes i do remember about the sql injection..but i don think thats the problem here...cos with very few necessary changes i got output with GET method...

Comment: ok ill look thru the link you gave...but pls do post me with anything else that comes to your mind...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the PHP page directly to see if there are any errors? You might also want to try using Firebug (for Firefox), or the developer tools in Chrome to make sure that the request is actually being sent, and inspect the result.

Is `Passwword` spelt that way in the database, or is it just a typo in your PHP?

Finally, while it won't cause you problems now, it might down the line: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) - a malicious user could pass some bad arguments and do nasty things to your database. You need to escape  `$username` before using it in a SQL query, e.g.:

```
"SELECT ... WHERE userhandle = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'"
```

Comment: yes passwword is spelt that way in my db:-)it was a spelling error...my php code is correct. i ran it in local host and it gave correct outputs...and thank you for the note on sql injection..it will be helpful...

Comment: Another thing is i tried echoing the value of $username n then $password in the php code in beginning. there was no alert..so i think the parameters r not reaching the php code at all..

Comment: Are you sure the browser is sending the request? Use Firebug/chrome dev tools/etc. Try alerting the value of readyState even if it's not 4, etc.